# Strongswan IKEv2 vpn on Windows 10 client "policy match error"

Tags: vpn, windows-10, strongswan, ikev2

I have the newest version of Strongswan vpn on my ubuntu server running.
I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ikev2-vpn-server-with-strongswan-on-ubuntu-18-04-2) here and got it to work on my android and Iphone.

Now I want to get it to work on my windows 10 laptop but when I try to connect via the vpn settings in windows I only get a "policy match error" and the event view gives me the error code "13868".

After much googling I still cant find any working solution.

What can I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is most likely that the Windows client proposes a weak Diffie-Hellman (DH) group (1024-bit MODP). That group is not used anymore by strongSwan unless the user configures it explicitly.

You have two options:

1. Configure Windows to use a stronger DH group. This can be done either

   - via [Set-VpnConnectionIPsecConfiguration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/vpnclient/set-vpnconnectionipsecconfiguration?view=win10-ps) PowerShell cmdlet, which allows enabling stronger DH groups (e.g. group 14/2048-bit MODP or 384-bit ECP) and even other algorithms (e.g. AES-GCM combined-mode encryption/integrity, which is more efficient, but needs to be enabled explicitly on the server too)
   - or via registry by adding the DWORD key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Rasman\Parameters\NegotiateDH2048_AES256`. Set it to `1` to enable (the other algorithms are still proposed), or `2` to enforce the use of 256-bit AES-CBC and 2048-bit MODP DH (only these will be proposed).
2. Add the proposed, weak DH group (1024-bit MODP) to the IKE proposal on the server (e.g. configure something like `ike=aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp3072-modp2048-modp1024`, which adds it at the end so other clients may use stronger DH groups).

Option 1 is definitely preferred.

Comment: Is this normal for win10 that they have a weak dh group?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.

Comment: how can no one have upvoted this yet ?! it is the definite answer.

Answer (score -1):

To find out what is the problem you should, as a first step, turn on logging and see what happens during the connection process. Here is the example config I use on my server.

**/etc/strongswan.d/charon-logging.conf**

```
charon {
    # Section to define file loggers, see LOGGER CONFIGURATION in
    # strongswan.conf(5).
    filelog {
        # <filename> is the full path to the log file.
        /var/log/strongswan.log {

            # Loglevel for a specific subsystem.
            # <subsystem> = <default>

            # If this option is enabled log entries are appended to the existing
            # file.
            append = yes

            # Default loglevel.
            default = 2

            # Enabling this option disables block buffering and enables line
            # buffering.
            # flush_line = no

            # Prefix each log entry with the connection name and a unique
            # numerical identifier for each IKE_SA.
            ike_name = yes

            # Adds the milliseconds within the current second after the
            # timestamp (separated by a dot, so time_format should end with %S
            # or %T).
            # time_add_ms = no

            # Prefix each log entry with a timestamp. The option accepts a
            # format string as passed to strftime(3).
            # time_format =
        }
    }
}
```

U can use it and analyze the log file to discover the issue. If you will not able to figure it out, post a connection log here I will try to help you.

Comment: I added this code to the conf file and restart the service with "systemctl restart strongswan". Tried to connect a few times with my windows laptop but I dont get a strongswan.log in /var/log/.

Comment: Try to create this file with `sudo touch /var/log/strongswan.log`. Restart strongswan with `sudo service ipsec restart` or the way you've done it before.

Comment: The problem could be that apparmor prevents the charon daemon from creating the log file.  Unless you're in a high-security production environment, I find it easiest to disable apparmor.